# python find specific variable in string

Tags: html, string, find, variable-assignment

I've been searching for the answer, but i really cannot find it, thanks for any possible answer!

I'm going through an html document full of random text, and i'm looking for something in a specific date format:

%%/%%/%% or %%-%%-%%

Two questions:
1-is it possible to do something like str.find(%s/%s/%s) while specifying the kind  of %s (two digits in this case)?

2-Is it possible to assign the %s to variables while doing the .find? Because something like str.find(%s/%s/%s) % ( d,m,y) gives an error.

Thumbs up for a hint on the python code to achieve this!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's very possible. [Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html) are going to be your best friend in this situation.

For the example you gave, where you're looking for things like "xx/xx/xx" such that each 'x' is a digit, the following regular expression will do the job: `\d\d[/]\d\d[/]\d\d`.

Here is how it would work in Python:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('\d\d[/]\d\d[/]\d\d')
pattern.findall(' sadfsd  04/06/76   kjadsf 10/10/14  ')
```

Try that out in your Python interpreter and you'll get a list of matching substrings:

```
['04/06/76', '10/10/14']
```

If you want to extract the day, month, and year individually, use parentheses to group those parts of the regular expression. Like so:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('(\d\d)[/](\d\d)[/](\d\d)')
pattern.findall(' sadfsd  04/06/76   kjadsf 10/10/14  ')
```

That gets you a list of tuples:

```
[('04', '06', '76'), ('10', '10', '14')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the super fast reply! i guess i'll take a deep look into them. Does it cover even the second question?

Comment: I don't understand the second question. Are you trying to get the values out individually? In other words, assign the date substring to `d`, and so on?

Comment: Yea my bad it was poorly presented but you already answered my 2dn  question with your more than fast answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: I updated my answer with an additional example. If I've answered your question completely, please accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: Sadly i've not enough reputation to upvote you yet, but it's a matter of days and i will come back to thank you again!